# IOS equivalent of abort() for assertion failures

Tags: ios, nsassert

Is there a simple way of throwing the exception generated by an `NSAssert` when the condition is false?  To draw a parallel of what I'm asking for: In C stdlib a failed assert results in a `printf()` and `abort()`.  And in Java, a failed assert results in a `java.lang.AssertionError`.  In ObjectiveC a failed assert seems to result in (copied from NSException.h):

```
[[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInMethod:_cmd
    object:self file:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__]
        lineNumber:__LINE__ description:(desc), ##__VA_ARGS__];
```

The best equivalent I can think of is either putting the above block in a macro I define (let's call it `NSFail()`), or using `NSAssert(NO, ...)`.  The `NSFail` macro is a little undesirable since it seems like I'm defining something that essentially already exists.  The `NSAssert(NO,...)` option is undesirable because I don't want the code disabled when `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is defined.

Comment: You can `abort()` in Objective-C too. Or `[[NSException new] throw]`.

Comment: If you like `assert` you can also use it. Note that the `assert`macro will expand to "void" when `NDEBUG` is defined,  while `NSAssert` and friends will expand to nothing when `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is defined. In Objective-C exceptions do not have much of a value, you SHALL abort as soon as possible, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

`[[NSException new] raise]`

You can also add descriptive reasons:

`[[NSException exceptionWithName:@"Impossible" reason:@"Something happened that was not supposed to" userInfo:nil] raise]`

[NSException apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/Reference/Reference.html)